# get typed word after some special character

Tags: jquery

I am tries to implement Facebook mention so after "@" word i need that word on key up. so fr that i have done

```
$('#post-desc-textarea').on('keyup', function (e) {
    var text = $(this).text();
    var split = text.split("@");
    var last word = split.pop();
});
```

but if i am tries to add in between already typed text then how can we find the word after @.

for example
 we have alreday type below text

`hi @abc @def @ghi`

and i want to add one new text in between `@abc and @def` like `@xyz`.

and when i typing that word i need to fetch only that word called `xyx`.

any help will be appreciate.

Comment: means you want last typed word ???

Comment: @PranayRana yes last type word but that can be in between string.

Comment: in that case you can store value of old string in onblur event and then check old and new value on onblur ...

Comment: @PranayRana no that will not help because if we store value on each keyup event then browser can be take more lode. and it will little slower.

Comment: I am suggesting you store value onFocus of element and do compare of new and stored value onBlur event ..that is the only way you can do

Comment: @PranayRana but i need to serch with that keyword on keyup like what user type based on that i need to find users from facebook. so this both event will not work for me.

Comment: Is [This](https://jsfiddle.net/pttxgeun/) what you want?

Comment: @Mr.x No i just want only that text that will be added last with @

Comment: Do you mean, you want to get last words entered while it has `@` ?

Comment: Try this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pttxgeun/1/)

Comment: @Mr.x not last word. last added word.

Comment: Little unclear what you want. did you try above fiddle? still no?

Comment: @Mr.x Still No, beacuse it will give us last @ value. but lets say i added `@abc `first thne i need `@abc` not `@you`

Comment: Let us  [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161523/discussion-between-ishan-shah-and-mr-x).